# .NET How to search and get list of users in Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I've never programmed against Active directory, and MVC before and need some advice.

I'm using following code to search, and get list of users in a view. I don't know if I'm on the right track, and how do I get it in a list view on cshtml?

```
   public ActionResult Find()
    {
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(
                      "LDAP://example..");

        DirectorySearcher searcher;
        SearchResultCollection results;

        searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

        searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(displayname=*))";
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

        using (searcher)
        {
            results = searcher.FindAll();

            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
               string searchOK = result.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString();
               objects.Add(searchOK);
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Do you still have the completed code available to post here? The code above is missing the initial declaration of `objects` and when I update my sln with this code, and the answer below, I just get a page that says System.String, there is no list.

Comment: Sorry @Jamie i don't have access to that code anymore.

Comment: No worries @Kasra I was able to figure it out and got my app built within a couple weeks of posting that comment. It was a great starting point!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass the list of users to the View:

```
return View(objects);
```

In your View, declare the type of your model on the top like this:

```
@model List<string>
```

And then you can access the list using the **@Model** Variable anywhere in your View.